# Is it possible to highlight particular page in kendo grid pager?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Is it possible to highlight particular page in kendo grid pager ?
I tried grid.dataSource.page(n) but it actually loads the page. What I want is I should be able to explicitly highlight say page 3 as selected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what you're trying to accomplish. It's just css so all you need to do is find the correct element in the pager. Something like this should work.

```
$('.k-grid-pager li:eq(4) a').css('background-color','yellow');
```

Comment: You gave me answer but in this case when you want to highlight another page you have to remove style  from previous page. This will solve my purpose but have to know the last selected page. I thought there should be some function to select particular page in grid.

Comment: If you don't to keep track of which one was `yellow`, you can define a CSS class for doing the same thing and then you search for which elements has this class and remove the class and then add it to the element that you want as @MalcolmBoyanton suggests

Comment: @ashy143 Why are you wanting to show a selected page that is not the actual selected page? That defeats the whole purpose of a pager.

Comment: @MalcolmBoyanton  I have 2-3 tabs in my screen for which I am using the same grid. So when tab is changed my datasource is changed and I get new data from service layer. So while making an ajax request my function transport.read(options)  has page information  in options pertaining to last tab (say I was on page 4 in last tab). Now when I load another tab I want to load page 1. So to achieve this I have a page number mapping for each tab. Every time I load any tab I take value from map and load that page and get expected data, but not able to modify the pager's page highlight.